# Cannot create a new user using ActiveAdmin with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, activeadmin

When I try to create a new user using Activeadmin, Rails throws the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::UsersController#create
undefined method `email' for #<User:0x007fabb13db508>
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"RS+AP9merlR5RxiKrPxM8Sx9CYEZGn7a4EJ6e25DL6Q=",
 "user"=>{"username"=>"user1",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Create User"}
```

Some background info: I have installed Activeadmin and besided the default admin_user resource, I created a user model using Devise and registered this user model as an Activeadmin resource. I want my users to authenticate using usernames and not emails, so I did the following migration:

```
def up
  add_column :users, :username, :string
  add_index :users, :username, unique: true, name: 'index_users_on_username', using: 'btree'
  remove_column :users, :email, :string
end

def down
  remove_column :users, :username, :string
  remove_index :users, :username
  add_column :users, :email, :string
end
```

In the devise initializer I set:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :username ]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :username ]
```

I also did the appropriate customizations of the login forms and the forms of the user resource in Activeadmin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  index do
    column :username
    default_actions
  end

  filter :username

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :username
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end

  controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit admin_user: [:username, :password, :password_confirmation]
    end
  end
end
```

I cannot determine if this is a Devise, Activeadmin, Postgres or Rails issue. Furthermore, I am not sure where to look for Admin::UsersController. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. In the Rails console tring to create a new user:

```
User.create(username: 'John', password: '123456', password_confirmation: '123456')
```

throws a similar error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for #<User:0x007fabb6806da8>
```

**Update 1:**

@Sparda: I added this to my user model (under app/models/user.rb):

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if username = conditions.delete(:username)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value", { :value => username.downcase }]).first
  else
    where(conditions).first
  end
end
```

restarted the server, but the same error is there.

@Adeptus: I added the two methods in add/admin/user.rb. Now the following happens - when I fill the form and click on Create user the page refreshes, the field of the forms get erased and only there is a flash error arround the password field `can't be blank`. Btw, I had already encountered this behaviour. I tried to readd the email column in the users table, but that same thing happend.

Comment: Write this in your `User` model and let me know what happens, if this works I'll write a complete answer `def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if username = conditions.delete(:username)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value", { :value => username.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end`

Comment: @Sparda - I answered your suggestion as an update in my question.

Comment: Well I won't be of any help... The only thing I can tell you is that I really think this comes from Devise since created a user in the console raises the same error. You should look in this direction.

Comment: Thank you. I saw [where](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address#tell-devise-to-use-login-in-the-authentication_keys) you took your suggestion. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Yep, I faced the issue before so I just had to take a look in my project but that is the actual place where I found it the first time ; ) Good luck mate

Comment: @Sparda - sorry for bugging you again, but one more thing - apparently the `where` clauses require the `meta_where` gem, which is not compatible with Rails >= 3.1 (and I am on Rails 4). The alternative is the `squeel` gem, but after installing it nothing changed. Can you remember if you had to do something in that direction in your project?

Comment: I am using Rails 4 and it works perfectly, `where` can still be used as it was before. If you are using MetaWhere at other places though, you actually might want to replace it for Squeel. Otherwise you don'y need neither one or the other.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39927/discussion-between-alex-popov-and-sparda)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to your model:

```
def email_required?
  false
end

def email_changed?
  false
end
```